# About Sending mail to all users form MYSQL in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am Very new in PHP would you anyone please help me about how can i sending mail form my MySQL database
to all users mail-address with the Post link ?

Thanks

Comment: Without your code its imposible to help you! add **your code and what you have tried untill now**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two steps in the process you want to achieve. First, you need to get a list of all the users from the database, and then you need to send the email to the right addresses.

Assuming you know how to loop through all users you need and `$r['email']` corresponds to the user's email, [mail()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) is what you're looking for and this example should get you somewhere:

```
while($r = fetch) { /* Depends on what you're using to connect to DB */
    $to = $r['email']; // Email address from database
    $subject = "Your subject here";
    $message = "Email contents here";
    $headers = "From: no-reply@example.com \r\n";
    $headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP/".phpversion();

    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
}
```

If you want to send nice looking HTML emails instead of plaintext, you'll have to look into something like [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)

Answer (score 0):

you have to retrive emails from your database and use the function mail() of the php
for more details please see this link http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mail_mail.asp